# Select distinct value based on id from linq query syntax with multiple joins

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

We are running into an issue where there are duplicate (identical) sessions in our Session table which is creating multiple PunchDetails when it should not be.

How can I get only Distinct SessionIds when joining on my session table?

```
            var costCodes = Context.Query<CostCodeEntity>();
            var locations = Context.Query<SiteEntity>();
            var sessions = Context.Query<SessionEntity>();
            var results = from punch in query
                          join costCode in costCodes on punch.CostCodeId equals costCode.Id
                          join location in locations on punch.LocationId equals location.Id into locationJoin
                          from location in locationJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          join session in sessions on punch.SessionId equals session.SessionUniqueidentifier into sessionJoin
                          from session in sessionJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new PunchDetail
                          {
                              Id = punch.Id,
                              EmployeeId = punch.EmployeeId,
                              LocationId = punch.LocationId
                          };
            return await results.ToListAsync();
```

Can I just throw a .Distinct() at the end of "sessionJoin.DefaultEmpty()"?

Comment: Begin with using [navigation properties instead of joins](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/). That often prevents duplication.

Comment: I would be more comfortable using navigation properties if we were in EF Core. This is an older solution and I believe that lazy loading isnt really an option on older versions so it may have adverse performance.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/#lazy-loading

Comment: Older versions have lazy loading by default, but you can easily turn it off. Navigation properties really are a must when working with EF.